# How to make atop exclude the statistics since boot?

Tags: linux, monitor

I have a linux box, whose resource utilization i need to monitor every hour. By resource, i mean mainly cpu, memory and network. I am using atop for the cpu memory and nethogs for the network utilization monitoring. I am thinking of redirecting the reports to text files and send them my email, but the initial startup screen for atop shows all statistics since boot, and it makes the text look messy, so is there a way to make atop skip the initial statistics ?

Comment: why dont you use something lightweight and simple like [SeaLion](http://sealion.com)?

Comment: For anyone looking for a way how to skip initial statistics in interactive mode of `atop`: hit `t` key on the keyboard, it will make a sample immediately and display it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use something other than atop. There are many other tools like top, free -m, etc for your cpu, memory and network statistics. The only disadvantage would be that you would have o write them independently.

Landed on your question as I was looking for just that. **[SeaLion](http://sealion.com)** actually works well for this purpose and also you wouldn't need to store them in files. It's all presented on a timeline so you can just "Jump to" whenever you want to check your data. You don't even manually have to record the data.

I suppose this is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem right now, I came up with

```
atop -PCPU,NET,DSK | sed -n -e '/SEP/,$p'
```

The `-P..` instructs atop to only show the requested information, so roll your own. The important bit is `sed` which skips lines until the first line containing `SEP` is found, which effectively skips over the first block of data containing the summary since boot time.

Answer (score -1):

I an not sure, but i think you can't because atop produce statistics over some interval. On the initial run there is no previous point, so atop produce stats since boot to current point, but you can easily use for example awk to parse the output:

```
    atop 1 2 | awk '/ seconds elapsed$/ {output=1;} {if (output) print}'
```

This is simplest way to solve problem with atop, but there is tons of other tools probably better suited for this job.

Comment: Can you please suggest any ?

Comment: It highly depends on which goal you wish to reach.
There are large nagios which can monitor whole network of hosts for absolutely all kind of activity and produce the not just reports but generate alerts.
If you have no need in per-process stats, there is sysstat package which records all general stats all the time for the last configurable time period. You can extract any piece any time.
There is vmstat, pidstat, ps, free depending on which exact stats you need which generally give you current snapshot without recording anything.